# Is there a way to handle URIError in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, decodeuricomponent

Some days ago I was working on an issue for my job where a page on React couldn't "catch" an error when someone tried to navigate using a bad URL that had the percentage sign (`%`) that can't be decoded.

The React project uses `react-router-dom` to handle navigation by showing different views when accessing different URL's (it even has a 404 route when it has no matching routes), and the struture looks very similar to React Router's 404 example, here's the [link](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match) where you can try for yourself adding `/%` to the URL from the sandbox's browser and understand in a better way the problem.

In my local-development scenario the page only shows the stack trace in the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/484nX.png) (also check the console output).

I understand that it if someone provides a bad URL that can't be decoded this error will throw and therefore the page will not run. I've been looking for a while and haven't found nothing related to how to catch it on React (I'm not sure if that's really possible).

Any suggestions are welcome!